# Opt in checkbox is not visible for tv app

Tags: android, android-tv

I created a TV app and uploaded to play store with following code in manifest, still the opt-in checkbox is not visible in pricing tab.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:banner="@drawable/logo"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
        <activity
            android:name="com.tv.activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/logo"
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:logo="@drawable/logo"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-tv.html#opt_in), if the opt-in checkbox is not enabled, check your APK to make sure it meets the initial criteria.

- Applications must include a list of categories for the [`CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LEANBACK_LAUNCHER) of [`ACTION_MAIN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN) the Intent type. For more information, click [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#tv-activity).
- Your application must state that it does not require a touch screen. List must `android:required="false"`declare `android.hardware.touchscreen`hardware. For more information, click [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#declare-hardware-requirements).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I did all you mentioned still I got the issue. Accidentally I done some changes and clicked submit update button at that point  opt-in checkbox got enabled. Looks like some refresh issue in there portal.